# ERROR: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected during sql script execution

Tags: postgresql

I have ~300 000 rows of data inserted by `.sql` script. When I start script execution like this:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$BLOCK$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
END
$BLOCK$;
```

In pgadmin I get error `ERROR: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected` after several minutes of execution. Do you know how can solve this issue?

Comment: It is clear that `INSERT INTO ...` includes a table name and a bunch of VALUEs. Show us a specific example that inserts two rows, and tell us whether it triggers the EOF error or not. Do some work to reduce your large Red (failing) test case so it is smaller and Green (good DB commit). That will help you to understand which row is causing trouble. Likely you have quoting issues, leading to a mis-parse of the INSERT statement. It might be a `'` single-quote, a `‘` "smart" quote, or a stray `\n` newline.

Comment: You should tackle the problem by looking into the PostgreSQL server log, so that you know what the server has to say about that. The answer will depend on it.

Comment: The problem is the block itself. When I run `BEGIN; .... COMMIT;` only it works. When I use the above block I get the exception.